# The page is not loading When i am useSelector in the code so that i can render the object which is available in the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am having a redux store where i successfully get the product but when i try to capture those products to show them in ui the page just hangs neither give error neither load

```
const {loading,error,products,productCount} =  useSelector(
    (state) => state.products
    );
```

This line of code fulfulling what i just said to capture products from our store But this line of code giving error to me if i comment this code and then run the page load but while this code in codebase page neither load neither give error just hang

[image]

Here is my Homepage.js where i am rendering the produtcs

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
import {getProduct} from "../../actions/productAction"
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from "react-redux"
// import Card from '../../components/Card';

const HomePage = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const {loading,error,products,productCount} =  useSelector(
    (state) => state.products
    );
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProduct());
    
  }, [dispatch])
  
  return (
    <>
    <section className="section-content">
      <div className="container">
        <header className="section-heading">
          <h3 className="section-title">Popular products</h3>
        </header>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3">
            
            
            {/* {products && products.map((products)=><Card prod={products}/>)} */}
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

Here is the error i am having in console

[image]

Here is the productReducer.js

```
import{
ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,CLEAR_ERRORS
}from "../constants/productConstant"


export const productsReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
            
            return{
                loading:true,
                products:[]
            }
            case ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
                return{
                    loading:false,
                    products:action.payload.products,
                    productsCount:action.payload.productsCount
                }
            case ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
                return{
                    loading:false,
                    products:action.payload.products
                }
            case CLEAR_ERRORS:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    error:null
                }
        default:
            return state
    }
  };
```

Here is my Product Action.js

```
import axios from "axios";

import{
ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,CLEAR_ERRORS
}from "../constants/productConstant"

export const getProduct = () => async(dispatch)=>{
    try {
        console.log("Got executed In dispatch")
        dispatch({type:ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST})

        const {data} = await axios.get("/api/v1/products")
        console.log(data)
        dispatch({
            type:ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload:data,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch({
            type:ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload:error.response.data.message,
        })
    }
}

export const clearErrors = () => async(dispatch)=>{
    dispatch({type:CLEAR_ERRORS}) 
}
```

Here is my store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { productsReducer } from './reducers/productReducer';




const reducer = combineReducers({
    product:productsReducer,
})

const initialState = {}

const middleWare = [thunk]
const store = createStore(reducer,initialState,composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare)))


export default store;
```

Comment: @DrewReese I did not see this error The error is saying that loading cant be destructure maybe because useSelector not defined when i remove loading then also i got the error the first thing which is in the list is not defined

Comment: You've a typo, when you combined the reducers you placed the products state under a `product` key, but in the `useSelector` hook you are selecting a `state.products` which is OFC undefined. Either fix the key to match what you are selecting, or fix the selector function to match the state key used. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Yes Thanks this works Sorry i bother you with a typo

Comment: Don't worry about it... we've all made mistakes like this. Good luck.

Comment: I want to accept answer for this kindly write answer

Comment: I understand and appreciate the sentiment, but it's an issue caused by a typo. It's one of those things that just isn't valuable as a QnA for future readers as it's *not* a very generalizable problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const {loading,error,products,productCount} =  useSelector(
    (state) => state.product
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).